# Extract the x/y part from a coordinate in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I extract only the x or y part of a predefined coordinate?

For instance, let's say we have

`\coordinate (A) at (1,2);`

And I want to use the x part of `(A)` like this

`\draw (x of A,3)--(0,0);`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not aware of any direct syntax to do that (though I would love to have one). You can however use the `let` operation (section 14.15 in the TikZ v2.10 manual):

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

[...]

\draw let \p1 = (A) in (\x1,3) -- (0,0);
```

Comment: I thought at first that `\pgfextractx` should work with `\coordinate`, but it doesn't.

Comment: @Gonzalo: `\newdimen\mydim`, `\pgfextractx\mydim{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}`.

Comment: thank you; `\pgfpointanchor` is what I didn't know.

Comment: You should point out that this requires the `calc` tikzlibrary.

Answer (score 3):

For the second part of your question: You can do that with the `|-` syntax.

```
\coordinate (A) at (1,2);

\draw (A |- 0,3) -- (0,0);
```

Note that for pgfplots you need to set the version to at least 1.11 (e.g., `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` or `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}`) or use coordinates in the `(axis cs:x,y)` format for the intended behaviour.

Comment: You do not need `tmp` here. You can use directly `(A|-0,3)` or even `(A|-,3)` (which is equivalent to `(A|-1,3)`) or `(,3-|A)`.

Comment: That's great! I updated the answer.