# Get x and y coordinates of a point in tkz?

Tags: tkz-collection

Is it possible to get the x or y coordinate of a Point with tkz? Especially if I have two points A=(a_1,a_2) and B=(b_1,b_2) I want to have a Point C=(a_1,b_2).

This is related to [Extract the x/y part from a coordinate in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14021/extract-the-x-y-part-from-a-coordinate-in-pgfplots). The difference is that I am asking for a way to to it in tkz.

Comment: TkZ points are just coordinate nodes. So you can use exactly the same solution.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't get it, how to apply this exactly to my example above?

Comment: Side remark: Direct coordinate calculations seem to be against the spirit of tkz-euclide (hence the name). Maybe `\tkzDefPointBy` can do what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TkZ points are just coordinate nodes. As such you can use and define them in the same way. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(2,2){B}
    \path let \p1=(A), \p2=(B) in (\x1,\y2) node[coordinate] (C) {};
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ye we can do that but I prefer to avoid the mix of syntaxes. I think it's preferable to create a new macro but this is possible ...

Answer (score 3):

You can  use the tikz possibilities, don't forget that you can use tikz and pgf at the same time with tkz.
Another possibility is to use (the next macro is in tkz)

```
\makeatletter
    \def\tkz@@extractxy#1{%
    \pgfextractx{\pgf@x}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}
    \pgfextracty{\pgf@y}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}} 
    } 
\makeatother
```

For example but I don't test it :

```
\makeatletter
\def\tkzExchangeCoord(#1,#2)#3{% 
\tkz@@extractxy{#1}%
\pgf@xa=\pgf@x\relax
\tkz@@extractxy{#2}%
\pgf@yb=\pgf@y\relax 
\path[coordinate](\pgf@xa,\pgf@yb) coordinate (#3);}
\makeatother
```

or more in the spirit of tkz

```
\makeatletter
\def\tkzExchangeCoord(#1,#2){% 
\tkz@@extractxy{#1}%
\pgf@xa=\pgf@x\relax
\tkz@@extractxy{#2}%
\pgf@yb=\pgf@y\relax 
\path[coordinate](\pgf@xa,\pgf@yb) coordinate (tkzPointResult);}
\makeatother
```

You can use the point with :

```
\tkzExchangeCoord(A,B)
\tkzGetPoint{H}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can make something easier with some tikz macros

Comment: Do you know why `\draw let \p1=(A), \p2=(B) in \pgfextra{\tkzDefPoint(\x1,\y2){C}};` doesn't work? (It results in `FP error: Illegal character p found in float number!`)

Comment: this is simple : `\x1` and `\y2` are lengths with pt or `\tkzDefPoint` uses numbers without units (by defaut the macro accepts only cm) so you need to remove pt