# How to access \xmin, \xmax, \ymin, \ymax from within PGFplots axis environment

Tags: pgfplots, intersections

In the MWE example below I have the values specified twice, but would prefer not to have to do that. Furthermore, it is possible to allow PGFplots to automatically select these end points so I would have to iterate and modify the settings manually after seeing what PGFplots had selected.  There must be some way to access these variables form within the `axis` environment:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-1.5, xmax=1.5, ymin=-1, ymax=3]

\addplot[mark=none, domain=-2.5:2.5, thick, red] ({x},{x*x-0.5});%

% Would prefer to be able to specify something like this:
%\addplot [mark=none, blue, ultra thick] coordinates {(\xmin,\ymin) (\xmin,\ymax)};

% But until I can access those values, do it manually:
\addplot [mark=none, blue, ultra thick] coordinates {(-1.5,-1) (-1.5,3)};

\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In case there is an interest in why I want to do this: I am trying to automate labelling intersections with the lines x=0 and y=0 within PGFplots as discussed in [How to specify a name path for the axis in PGFplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21740/how-to-specify-a-name-path-for-the-axis-in-pgfplots).  However, there are issues with that approach. One solution (albeit it is a bit of a hack) is to draw the lines x=0, and y=0 with `draw=none` option and then find the intersection with that.  If I can access the min/max values of the x and y axis then I can label a phantom line and automate the location of the intersections via [Intersections in PGFplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21408/intersections-in-pgfplots)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can access the values of `xmin`, `xmax`, etc. through `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}`. This only works if they have been set explicitly in the axis options, though, so it is most likely not what you want. Instead, you should use the nodes `current axis.above origin`, `current axis.below origin`, `current axis.left of origin` and `current axis.right of origin`.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[] 

\addplot[mark=none, domain=-2.5:2.5, thick, red] ({x},{x*x-0.5});% 

\draw (current axis.above origin) -- (current axis.below origin);
\draw (current axis.left of origin) -- (current axis.right of origin);

\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Like Jake says, `xmin`, etc. can only be accessed and stored via `pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}` and `\pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/xmin}{\xmin}` respectively, when `xmin` has been set explicitly.

Nonetheless besides the mentioned `current axis.above origin`, etc., `PGFplots` also offers `current axis.south west`, etc.. These represent nodes with coordinates `(xmin,ymin)`, etc., which is what you were looking for I believe.

However, I, unfortunately, do not know how to extract a `x` or `y` from the node coordinate. At [Extract the x/y part from a coordinate in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14021/extract-the-x-y-part-from-a-coordinate-in-pgfplots) it is stated that one can do so by means of `\newdimen\mydim, \pgfextractx\mydim{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}` but I cannot seem to get it to work.