# How to change only the last xticklabel?

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to set the last `xticklabel` to `\infty`. How can this be achieved without necessarily knowing the `xtick` value?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xticklabel={\tick >= 24 ? $\infty$ : $\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$}
    ]
      \addplot+[] table {\somedata};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(note: the above inline conditional doesn't work at all, it's just to illustrate what I am trying to do)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I would be best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  This would also ensure that the proposed solution actually works for your case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can assign names to the label nodes and access the last one through that. The node text can't be changed after it has been created, unfortunately, so you will have to paint over it with the changed label. Here's a new style called `overwrite last x tick label` that takes an optional argument to specify what the last label should be overwritten with. The style first draws a white rectangle over the old label and then puts a new node on top of that. That ensures that the old label is completely covered, even if the new label takes up less space.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
    overwrite last x tick label/.style={
        every x tick label/.append style={alias=lasttick},
        extra description/.append code={
            \fill [white] (lasttick.north west) ++(0pt,-\pgflinewidth) rectangle (lasttick.south east);         
            \node [anchor=base] at (lasttick.base) {#1};}
    },
    overwrite last x tick label/.default={$\infty$}
}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[overwrite last x tick label]
      \addplot table [row sep=crcr]{
      0 1\\
      2 1\\
      3 2\\
      4 3\\};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Jake! Works like a charm. I needed to add a yshift though: `\node [anchor=base,yshift=.2ex] at (lasttick.base) {#1};` for the `\infty` to be displayed nicely.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the axis description coordinate system:

[image]

### Notes:

- Needed to add `clip=false` to the axis.
- The `fill=whites` is so that the real label is hidden below the `\infty`.
- `draw=none` can be omitted.
- `yshift=1.5ex` was necessary to get the label in the correct vertical position. Perhaps there is a better way to do this.
- If you explicitly specify `xmax` in the axis options you can access this value thru `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}` as per [How to access \xmin, \xmax, \ymin, \ymax from within PGFplots axis environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22018/how-to-access-xmin-xmax-ymin-ymax-from-within-pgfplots-axis-environment).

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[clip=false] 

\addplot {x}; 

\node[draw=none,yshift=1.5ex,fill=white] at (xticklabel cs:1) {$\infty$};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can also work with: `\begin{axis}[
extra x ticks=6,
extra x tick labels={$\infty$},
extra x tick style={tick label style={fill=white}},
] `

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: That seems useful, but how can yo adapt that to work without knowing the `6` value specified in `extra x ticks=6`.

Comment: I don't know. I used this code some time ago ;-)

Comment: Thanks guys! Don't you think that this inline conditional `xticklabel={\tick >= 24 ? $\infty$ : $\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$}` would be the cleanest solution? Maybe it just needs a tiny change to work. Then one could maybe combine it with `\nexttick`.

Comment: @Fabian: I don't know how to make that syntax work. Even still, that would require that you know a maximum value for the tick label.

Answer (score 3):

You can use TeX (or LaTeX) conditionals based on `\tick pt` as long as the numbers are within the LaTeX number range -16384...16384. Here, the suffix `pt` allows you to apply fixed point arithmetics (because `pt` are represented as fixed point numbers in TeX):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xticklabel={\ifdim\tick pt<6pt $\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$ \else $\infty$\fi}
    ]
      \addplot+[] {x};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here, I chose "6" as the right-most value.

Clearly, the approach needs manual tuning because it assumes that there is  exactly one tick with position >= 6.