# Tufte like axis with pgfplots for log axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tufte

I used the excellent code from TUGBoat issue 34 mentioned in this post [Tufte like axis with pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155194/tufte-like-axis-with-pgfplots) and was very happy until I tried to use it with logarithmic axis. The problem seems to be that the values stored in `\pgfplots@data@xmin` etc. are logarithmic.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

    % automatically save the min and max value of the data
    % this part is crucial for me since I do not want to find the min and max values manually in a large data file.
    \makeatletter
    \def\pgfplotsdataxmin{\pgfplots@data@xmin}
    \def\pgfplotsdataxmax{\pgfplots@data@xmax}
    \def\pgfplotsdataymin{\pgfplots@data@ymin}
    \def\pgfplotsdataymax{\pgfplots@data@ymax}
    \makeatother

    % This adds the min and max values found above as extra ticks
    \pgfplotsset{tufte extra ticks/.style={
            extra x ticks={
                \pgfplotsdataxmin,
                \pgfplotsdataxmax
            },
            extra y ticks={
                \pgfplotsdataymin,
                \pgfplotsdataymax
            },
    }}  

    \pgfplotsset{
        range frame/.style={
            tick align=outside,
            axis line style={opacity=0},
            after end axis/.code={
                \draw ({rel axis cs:0,0}-|{axis cs:\pgfplotsdataxmin,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,0}-|{axis cs:\pgfplotsdataxmax,0});
                \draw ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,\pgfplotsdataymin}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,\pgfplotsdataymax});
            }
        }
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    range frame,
    xlabel={$L$ [H]},
    ylabel={$\hat{I}_{DM}$ [A]},
    axis lines*=left,
    ymin=0.41,
    ytick={0.7,0.9,...,1.5},
    xtick={1.5e-3,2e-3,2.5e-3},
    tufte extra ticks,
    xmode=log, % <- comment this out to get a working example
    ]
    \addplot +[black, mark options=fill=black] coordinates {(948e-6,1.61981) (1.5e-3,1.02377) (2e-3,0.769047) (2.5e-3,0.614994) (3.2e-3,0.503511)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to solve this problem if one or both axis are in log-mode?

**Edit:** `tufte extra ticks` has the purpose to create a tick for the minimal and maximal value of each axis as in the image below.

[image]

Comment: have you tried to use the new `axis line shift` key introduced in PGFPlots v1.13? I think this works fine also for logarithmic axis.

Comment: I gave it a quick shot and it solves the problem partially i.e. I can't get `tufte extra ticks` to work and I have to see how to shift the labels together with the axis.

Comment: shifting is not a problem, but I don't know what you want to do with the `extra ticks`. Could you explain this in more detail, please.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As already mentioned in [the comment to the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299186/tufte-like-axis-with-pgfplots-for-log-axis#comment724224_299186) -- in PGFPlots v1.13 the key `axis line shift` has been introduced which allows to easily produce Tufte like axis (have a look at [section 4.9.10 on page 255 in the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=255)). However, v1.13 does not take into account the axis labels, etc. when shifting the axis. This has been reported on the [PGFPlots bug tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/121/) and has been fixed in v1.14 released on 2016-08-10.

Said that it remains the problem of adding the `xmin` and `xmax` values as labels to the axis. I think at present there is no other way then setting the `xmin` and `xmax` values as options by hand to the axis and then you can add them as `xticks` or `extra x ticks` using the `\pgfkeysvalueof` command. This is supported by the answers given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22018/how-to-access-xmin-xmax-ymin-ymax-from-within-pgfplots-axis-environment).

(A bit strange though is, that when given `xmin=9e-4` the value stored is `-7.01` as can be seen by the added gray node. Jake has pointed out in the [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299186/tufte-like-axis-with-pgfplots-for-log-axis#comment724309_299200) that this is because the numbers are always stored in natural log, so `exp(-7.01)=0.0009`. This explains why the number is not shown as `10^(-3.05)=0.0009`.)

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            % use Tufte like axis
            axis line shift=10pt,
            % because of a bug in v1.13 one has to shift the labels, etc.
            % by hand. This is not necessary in v1.14!
            xlabel style={
                yshift=-10pt,
            },
            ylabel style={
                yshift=10pt,
            },
            %
            % to set some extra ticks at the beginning and the end of the
            % axis you have to give the values explicitly
            xmin=9e-4,
            xmax=4e-3,
            % now you can add them as extra ticks
            extra x ticks={
                \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},
                \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}
            },
            %
%            % if you want to change the tick label style to `i \cdot 10^j'
%            % (where `i' has to be an integer, e.g. $2 \cdot 10^{-3}$)
%            xticklabel style={
%                log identify minor tick positions=true,
%            },
            %
            xlabel={$L$ [H]},
            ylabel={$\hat{I}_{DM}$ [A]},
            axis lines*=left,
            %
            ymin=0.41,
            ytick={0.7,0.9,...,1.5},
            xtick={1.5e-3,2e-3,2.5e-3},
            %
            xmode=log,
        ]
            \addplot +[black, mark options=fill=black] coordinates {(948e-6,1.61981) (1.5e-3,1.02377) (2e-3,0.769047) (2.5e-3,0.614994) (3.2e-3,0.503511)};

            % for debugging show the value of `xmin'
            % (--> why does it show a value of -7.01?)
            \node [fill=black!25,anchor=south west] at (rel axis cs:0,0)
                {xmin = \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}}};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

---

### Solution with extracting the min and max values from a table

To "extract" the min and max value of the data you could put them into a table and then using the `pgfplotstable` package to sort and extract the data.

For more details have a look at the comments in the code.

```
    % first put the data to an external file or a table,
    % so it can be handled by the `pgfplotstable' package
    \begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
        948e-6  1.61981
        1.5e-3  1.02377
        2e-3    0.769047
        2.5e-3  0.614994
        3.2e-3  0.503511
    \end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        fpu,
        positioning,    % <-- for debugging nodes only
    }
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.13,
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % to be sure that no numbers are interpreted as zero, activate `fpu'
        % library
        \tikzset{
            fpu=true,
        }
            %%% find `xmin' and `xmax'
            % for that first sort the table after the x values
            \pgfplotstablesort{\SortedTable}{data.txt}
        \tikzset{
            fpu=false,
        }
            % then one can directly extract `xmin'
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index] 0}\of\SortedTable
                \let\xmin=\pgfplotsretval
            %% now extract `xmax'
            % for that we first need to extract the number of rows in the table
            \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\SortedTable}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\NoOfRows}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
            % then we can extract the last entry in the sorted table
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\NoOfRows}{[index] 0}\of\SortedTable
                \let\xmax=\pgfplotsretval


        \begin{axis}[
            % use Tufte like axis
            axis line shift=10pt,
            % because of a bug in v1.13 one has to shift the labels, etc.
            % by hand
            xlabel style={
                yshift=-10pt,
            },
            ylabel style={
                yshift=10pt,
            },
            %
            % add the extra ticks from the extracted data
            extra x ticks={
                \xmin,
                \xmax
            },
            % just to make sure these are the extra ticks, draw them red
            extra x tick style={
                text=red,
            },
            %
%            % if you want to change the tick label style to `i \cdot 10^j'
%            % (where `i' has to be an integer, e.g. $2 \cdot 10^{-3}$)
%            xticklabel style={
%                log identify minor tick positions=true,
%            },
            %
            xlabel={$L$ [H]},
            ylabel={$\hat{I}_{DM}$ [A]},
            axis lines*=left,
            %
            ymin=0.41,
            ytick={0.7,0.9,...,1.5},
            xtick={1.5e-3,2e-3,2.5e-3},
            %
            xmode=log,
        ]
            \addplot +[black, mark options=fill=black] table {data.txt};

            % for debugging show the value of `xmax'
            \node [fill=black!25,anchor=south west] (a) at (rel axis cs:0,0)
                {xmax = \pgfmathprintnumber{\xmax}};
            \node [fill=black!25,above=1pt of a.north west,anchor=south west]
                {Rows = \pgfmathprintnumber{\NoOfRows}};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of the second code block]

Comment: Your answer is definitively an improvement to my version. However, I think the whole purpose of `\def\pgfplotsdataxmin{\pgfplots@data@xmin}` etc. is to access `xmin` directly from the data. This nearly works, but the function `\pgfplotsdataxmin` returns `log(xmin)` since the axis is in log mode. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: @Stefan: about the value of xmin: `exp(-7.01)=0.0009`

Comment: @Jake, that is interesting. Isn't the logarithmic axis to the basis 10? Why should then the value be stored to the basis of e? Is this a bug?

Comment: @Stefan: internally, the numbers for logarithmic plots are always stored as the natural log and only transformed to base 10 for printing or determining the tick positions.

Comment: @Jake, do you have an idea why the commented line `\pgfplotstablegetelem{\NoOfRows}{[index] 0}\of\SortedTable` in my second solution isn't working? Using that returns the value `1.5e-3` which corresponds to the index `1`, although the index is correctly shown in the node ...  (I remember that I had the same problem providing another answer some day.)

Comment: Thx. I hoped to use the values calculated by pgfplots (`\pgfplots@data@xmin` etc) and just call `exp(\pgfplots@data@xmin)` or similar. I will leave the question open for a few more days and check yours correct there is no better solution.