# PGFPlots gap between axes and data

Tags: pgfplots

Does anyone know how to put a gap between the axes and data in PGFPlots? Essentially I'm looking to use Jean-Luc Doumont's style from his excellent book *Trees, Maps, and Theorems*. Figure here is from http://www.treesmapsandtheorems.com/pdfs/TM&Th-4.0-summary.pdf. [image: Axes removed from data]

Don't worry about the arrows and everything, that is all straightforward. I am specifically asking about the axes position.

Comment: Are you searching for something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299200/95441?

Comment: Hero. Yes, that is what I was looking for. Thanks.